# byte_size vs String.length in elixir

Tags: string, binary, elixir

I decided to build my own CSV parser in elixir as a practice project and managed to get something working without too much hassle.

I know that this was a problem that had been solved in the past by some of the "top" elixir devs so I decided to take a look at how they went about it.

I started looking at the source code for the elixir module [NimbleCSV](https://github.com/plataformatec/nimble_csv). It was written by José Valim, the creator of the language, with contributions from a few notable elixir devs so I thought that this was a good choice.

In the `parse_string` function they check for the strings length with the function `byte_size(string)`. I think I understand how this function works. e.g.

```
iex()> byte_size(<<104, 101, 108, 108, 111>>)
5
iex()> byte_size(<<104, 101, 108, 108, 111::9>>)
6
```

The first function is `40 bits` which is `5 bytes` (each value in the binary defaults to 8 bits in elixir if not told otherwise)

In the second I am assigning one of the values to be `9 bits` so the total is `41 bits`. This means that it is `6 bytes` (due to rounding)

> sorry if some of the language is not exactly right

That makes sense to me. My, question is why would they choose this function over `String.length` in this case? If they are just getting the length of a string wouldn't both return the same result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`String.length/1` returns the numbers of [graphemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grapheme) (each one may be one or more than one byte), while `byte_size/1` deals with raw data bytes.

```
iex> byte_size "‍‍"
18
iex>  "‍‍" <> <<0>>
<<240, 159, 145, 169, 226, 128, 141, 240, 159, 145, 169, 226, 128, 141, 240, 159, 145, 167, 0>>

iex> String.length "‍‍"
1

iex> String.length "a"
1
iex> byte_size "a"
1
```

from the [doc](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#module-string-and-binary-operations):

> String and binary operations
>
> To act according to the Unicode Standard, many functions in this module run in linear time, as they need to traverse the whole string considering the proper Unicode codepoints.
>
> For example, `String.length/1` will take longer as the input grows. On the other hand, `Kernel.byte_size/1` always runs in constant time (i.e. regardless of the input size).

Not directly relevant but if you want to know more about Unicode and char encoding, you can read [this article](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) and watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YUnCRY5e7KQ)

Comment: Another reason is we cannot pattern match on graphemes and the whole implementation is based on binary matches, which gives a performance boost on e. g. [looking up newlines](https://github.com/plataformatec/nimble_csv/blob/master/lib/nimble_csv.ex#L385). Basically, we need to grab row delimiters and cell delimiters, and since `NimbleCSV` does not allow UTF-8 _delimiters_, it’s possible in general to forget about Unicode and treat everything between delimiters as binary garbage.

Comment: That said, if one wants a ESV (for Emoji Serarated Values :), the implementation must use `String`s.